# Get 2 Different arrays of top 4 Key and Value as per top values from JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Let's say I have a JSON object.

```
var JSONObj = "skills":[
            {
                "skill": "HTML",
                "rate": "4"
            },
            {
                "skill": "JS",
                "rate": "5"
            },
            {
                "skill": "jQuery",
                "rate": "8"
            },
            {
                "skill": "Angular 2",
                "rate": "1"
            },
            {
                "skill": "XML",
                "rate": "3"
            },
            {
                "skill": "CSS",
                "rate": "10"
            }
        ]
```

I want to generate 2 different arrays for TopRates and TopSkills based on their rate in Javascript.
e.g, 
`var TopSkills = ["CSS", "jQuery", "JS", "HTML"];
var TopRates = [10, 8, 5, 4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to return arrays of skills and rates and then `slice()` to return top 4.

```js
var JSONObj = {
  "skills": [{
    "skill": "HTML",
    "rate": "4"
  }, {
    "skill": "JS",
    "rate": "5"
  }, {
    "skill": "jQuery",
    "rate": "8"
  }, {
    "skill": "Angular 2",
    "rate": "1"
  }, {
    "skill": "XML",
    "rate": "3"
  }, {
    "skill": "CSS",
    "rate": "10"
  }]
}

var r = JSONObj.skills.sort((a, b) => b.rate - a.rate).reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.skills = (r.skills || []).concat(e.skill);
  r.rates = (r.rates || []).concat(e.rate);
  return r;
}, {})

var TopSkills = r.skills.slice(0, 4);
var TopRates = r.rates.slice(0, 4);
console.log(TopSkills)
console.log(TopRates)
```

Comment: Superb @Nenad! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array by rate first, then map with skill and rate:

```
var sortedBySkill = JSONObj.skills.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.rate - a.rate;
});

console.log(sortedBySkill.map(function(a) {
    return a.skill;
}).slice(0,4));

console.log(sortedBySkill.map(function(a) {
    return a.rate;
}).slice(0,4));
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c56zmenv/1/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

or even easily with forEach

```
var topSkills = [];
var topRates = [];
JSONObj.skills.sort((a, b) => b.rate - a.rate).forEach(item => {
  topSkills.push(item.skill);
  topRates.push(item.rate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var JSONObj = [{"skill":"HTML","rate":"4"},{"skill":"JS","rate":"5"},{"skill":"jQuery","rate":"8"},{"skill":"Angular 2","rate":"1"},{"skill":"XML","rate":"3"},{"skill":"CSS","rate":"10"}]

JSONObj.sort(function(a,b){return  parseFloat(a.rate) - parseFloat(b.rate)});
JSONObj.reverse();

var TopSkills=[];
var TopRates=[];

for(var i=0;i<JSONObj.length;i++){
  TopRates.push(JSONObj[i].rate);
  TopSkills.push(JSONObj[i].skill);
}
```

Check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tojopaul/o393rhgv/)